# Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}p(x)=\infty,p(x)=a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}+a_{2n}x^{2n}+...+a_0, a_{2n+1}>0$

Tags: real-analysis

$p(x)= x^{2n+1}(a_{2n+1}+\frac{a_{2n}}{x}+...+\frac{a_0}{x^{2n+1}})(*)$

I am trying to find an explicit $x_0$ such that

$\forall_{r\in\mathbb{R}}\exists_{x_0\in\mathbb{R}}\forall_{x\in\mathbb{R}}:x\in(x_0‌​,+\infty)\Rightarrow p(x)>r$.

First I take some $\epsilon > 0$ and now I am looking for a $x_0$ such that

$|\frac{a_{2n}}{x}+...+\frac{a_0}{x^{2n+1}}|\leq\epsilon$.

If I assume $x>1$ I can make the estimate

$|\frac{a_{2n}}{x}+...+\frac{a_0}{x^{2n+1}}|\leq|\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{2n}a_i}{x}|$

which should be

$\leq$then $\epsilon \iff \frac{|\sum_{i=0}^{2n}a_i|}{\epsilon}\leq |x|$.

Therefore $x_0=\frac{|\sum_{i=0}^{2n}a_i|}{\epsilon}$ Because we have just fixated an $\epsilon$ we can treat it as an constant and choose

$x^{2n+1}\geq\frac{r}{a_{2n+1}+\epsilon}$

Therefore $x_1=\sqrt[2n+1]{\frac{r}{a_{2n+1}+\epsilon}}$ and $x_2:=\max(x_1,x_0)$

But here is the Problem. If I would calculate the value for $p(x_2)$ on the left side of the equation $(*)$ I would get

$\frac{r}{a_{2n+1}+\epsilon}+A,A>0$

Because $x^{2n+1}>\frac{r}{a_{2n+1}+\epsilon}$ the actual value must be bigger. Simmilarilay for the Right side

Because $a_{2n+1}+\frac{a_{2n}}{x}+...\frac{a_0}{x^{2n+1}}\leq a_{2n+1}+|\frac{a_{2n}}{x}+...\frac{a_0}{x^{2n+1}}|\leq a_{2n+1}+|\sum_{i=0}^{2n}a_i|\leq a_{2n+1}+\epsilon,x\geq x_2$

Therefor the actual value for $p(x_2)$ on the Right side side would be $a_{2n+1}+\epsilon - B,B>0$.

In conclusion

$p(x_2)= (\frac{r}{a_{2n+1}+\epsilon}+A)((a_{2n+1}+\epsilon) -B) $ which should be $\geq$ than $r$

Which is only true if

$A(a_{2n+1}+\epsilon)-\frac{Br}{a_{2n+1}+\epsilon}\geq AB$.

How can I proof that?

Comment: If you add some spacing and some double $$, it might be a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of $\infty$ limit, given $r>0$ you need to find $x_r$ such that

> for every $x>x_r$, $p(x)>r$

The inequality becomes
$$
x^{2n+1}\left(1+\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+1}x}+\frac{a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n+1}x^2}+\dots+\frac{a_0}{a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}\right)
>\frac{r}{a_{2n+1}}
$$
For $k=0,1,\dots,2n$, you can find $y_k$ such that
$$
-\frac{1}{4n}<\frac{a_{k}}{a_{2n+1}x^k}<\frac{1}{4n}
$$
for $x>y_k$ (prove it). Therefore, for $x>x_1=\max\{y_0,y_1,\dots,y_k\}$,
$$
-\frac{1}{2}<\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+1}x}+\frac{a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n+1}x^2}+\dots+\frac{a_0}{a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}<\frac{1}{2}
$$
Thus, for $x>x_1$,
$$
1+\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+1}x}+\frac{a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n+1}x^2}+\dots+\frac{a_0}{a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}>\frac{1}{2}
$$
Now you are to find $x_2$ such that, for $x>x_2$,
$$
x^{2n+1}>\frac{2r}{a_{2n+1}}
$$
which of course is
$$
x_2=\sqrt[2n+1]{\frac{2r}{a_{2n+1}}}
$$
Finally, take $x_0=\max\{x_1,x_2\}$.